# Equal height of flex columns

Tags: html, css, angular

working on the displaying of tournament pairs in a tournaments tree view

the issue is that bracket columns are filled with different quantities of pairs so `flex` gives them different height

I need  them to be equal so I can layout pairs in a way that pair was in the middle between 2 pairs from the previous column

like:

```
pair1
      pair 5
pair2

pair3
      pair 6
pair4
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flex">
              <div *ngFor='let stage of stages; let i = index' class="bracket-column flex-column">
                <div *ngFor='let pair of stage; let last = last' class="flex bracket-wrapper" style="flex: 1 !important">
                  <div *ngIf="pair.bracket === 1" class="bracket">
                    <p class="flex" [class.glow-text]='pair.score_participant_one > pair.score_participant_two'>{{pair.participant_one.user.username}} <span class="score">{{pair.score_participant_one}}</span></p>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="flex" [class.glow-text]='pair.score_participant_one < pair.score_participant_two'>{{pair.participant_two ? pair.participant_two?.user.username : 'BYE' }} <span class="score">{{pair.participant_two ? pair.score_participant_two : '-'}}</span></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.bracket-column
  margin-right: 2em
  flex: 1 !important
  box-sizing: border-box !important
  height: 100% !important

.bracket
  margin-bottom: 1em
  padding: 0.5em
  border: 2px solid styles.$highlight-color
  width: 150px
  background-color: styles.$additional-darker-color
  p
    margin: 0
    width: 100%
    color: styles.$additional-color
    span
      color: white

.flex
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center

.flex-column
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: flex-start
```

Current Look:[image: current look]

Comment: why not use CSS-Grid? Flexbox is only good for controlling one direction. If you need to cotnrol both height and width at the same time, you should sue css-grid!

Comment: @tacoshy never used it, don't know how to manipulate it
U think it is impossible with Flex?

Comment: it's not impossible but grid is better option

Comment: @RKazmi share please if u have solution
basically except for the issue I mentioned it meets my requirements

Comment: You could also try to implement it yourself, you might find it's not as complicated as you might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 flex containers if you want to solve it with `flexbox`.

1. Add a container for all the columns. In you picture you have 3 columns and as such you need to add 3 columns within that container.
2. Add the boxes for the matches within another flex-container. Apply `flex-direction: column` to align them below each other.
3. Apply `justify-content: space-around;` to align them as intended.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column-flex {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* for demonstration purpose only */
.column-flex {
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.column-flex > div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-flex">
  <div>Quarter Finals 1</div>
  <div>Quarter Finals 2</div>
  <div>Quarter Finals 3</div>
  <div>Quarter Finals 4</div>
</div>
<div class="column-flex">
  <div>Semi Finals 1</div>
  <div>Semi Finals 2</div>
</div>
<div class="column-flex">
  <div>Finals</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!
Thanks!